# How to fill a 2d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Ok, so I'm new to 2d arrays and I'm trying to fill my 2d array that has the dimensions of 3x5. I want to make it so that the numbers 1-15 fill the array and if the dimensions are changed, like 6x7, it fills it with numbers 1-42. Any help would be appreciated.  For the filling, I need a nested for loop and to print it out I need to use a nested for each loop.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-arrays-in-java/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick.

```
 int nRow = 3;
 int nCol = 5;
 int [][] myArr = new int [nRow][nCol]; //Can replace this with input from user.

  int counter = 1; //Our counter
  for(int i = 0; i < nRow; i++){ //ROW
      for(int j = 0; j < nCol; j++){ //COL
          myArr[i][j] = counter;
          counter = counter + 1;
      }
  }
```

Output ->

```
 1,2,3,4,5,
 6,7,8,9,10,
 11,12,13,14,15
```

Comment: instead of a nested for loop, how would it work if it was a nested for each loop?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
int numRows = 3;
int numCols = 5;    

int[][] arr = new int[numRows][numCols];
int counter = 1;

for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
        arr[row][col] = counter;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can generate matrix as shown below

```
private static int[][] createMatrix(int row , int column){
    int[][] matrix = new int[row][column];
    int value = 1;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < row ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < column ; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = value++;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Solution class for your quick testing

```
public class Solution {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = createMatrix(3, 5);
    printMatrix(matrix);
 }

 private static int[][] createMatrix(int row, int column) {
    int[][] matrix = new int[row][column];
    int value = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = value++;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
 }

 private static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: i should've clarified I'm a beginner in coding so maybe static headers arent the way to go for me. thank you though